# How do I check whether a number is divisible by 2*M_PI in c++?

Tags: c++, division, pi

This is what I've done for checking the divisibility of a number by 2*M_PI. "w" is a constant that's 2/3 and t is the variable that varies by t += dt, where dt is 0.1. I'm trying to use the mod operator, %, to see if something is divisible. But its not working.

bool divisible;
real w = 2/3;
real t;

```
if((w*t) % 2*M_PI == 0)
    {
        divisible = true;
    }

else
    {
        divisible = false;
    }
```

This is the error that I get, "invalid operands of types ‘real’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator%’"

What does this mean? How do I get this to work? So do I need to make w and t an int? They can't be because w is 2/3, and t increments from 0 by 0.1. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just check `cos(w*t) == 0` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::fmod` instead, it operates on doubles rather than the integral `%` operator.

Comment: And look out for rounding errors, i.e. don't compare using `==` but see if you are within an acceptable epsilon from the desired value.

Comment: I'm getting compiling errors, w is a double, t is a double, and M_PI a floating point I think? Should, fmod((w*t)/(2*M_PI)) work?

Comment: @QEntanglement, did you look at the signature for the function? I left out a link on purpose (i.e. for you to do a little lateral thinking! ;) )

Comment: I'm a beginner. What do you mean signature for the function? I saw that "modf" splits the integer part from the float parts. I don't know how I will use this.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are or not, I hinted which function you should look at - did you for example search for this function? And if you had, you would have seen what the signature is (i.e. what parameters it accepts, and what it returns etc.) This will help you greatly when you actually come to use it. And as I said below, `modf` is **not** a modulo operation, it simply breaks the passed in value to integral and fractional quantities.

Answer (score 2):

'%' is the integer modulo operator not working for float/double arguments/operands

There exists a float/double modf function in math.h which may help

- an example may be found at e.g.
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/

Comment: `modf` is not a modulo operation, it simply breaks the double into integral and fractional parts.

Comment: The calculation step for the first argument used in the function modf call: double arg1 = (w*t) / 2*M_PI. If the result (fraction part) is or is almost 0.0 then the variable divisible (in the example of the question) has to be set to true. Don't forget - the results were influenced by limited floating point precision and perhaps assert M_PI to be inequal 0!

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to know if a floating-point number is **exactly** divisible by another one?

Floating-point arithmetics should not be used for "precise" calculations. The outcome of every operation is defined strictly, but it differs from the mathematical meaning of the same operation.
In particular:

```
double a = 1e20;
double b = 1e-20;

double c = (a + b) - a;
```

You might expect that `c` will be equal to `b`, but in fact it won't!

You should only compare floating-point numbers with some window. Means - does the specific floating-point value lie within some finite-length range.